# How to ZIP specific files from a folder using Winzip command line?

Tags: command-line, winzip

With this command, I'm able to ZIP all files from the folders:

```
wzzip.exe -a -p -r C:\DestinationPath\DataFiles_20130903.zip C:\SourcePath\*.*
```

But, my folder has .dat,.bat,.txt,.xls files.I want to ZIP only .dat and .bat file.How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe use wzzip.exe -a -p -r C:\DestinationPath\DataFiles_20130903.zip C:\SourcePath\\*.dat C:\SourcePath\\*.bat

Comment: @r3ap3r Thanks.It worked.But the problem is, I have to keep 20 files.I have to write it 20 times with file extension.Any other way to avoid this?

Comment: what do you mean by " I have to keep 20 files"? do you have 20 different file extensions? Please explain your scenario.

Comment: 20 is just an example. But I have multiple types of file.I want to make it configurable.Probable I have to write code for this...right??

Comment: yes, you will have to write code to make the command configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this command (for the particular scenario in the question):

```
wzzip.exe -a -p -r C:\DestinationPath\DataFiles_20130903.zip C:\SourcePath\*.dat C:\SourcePath\*.bat
```

for more command line options for winZip refer to the following links:

[winZip command line Reference 1](http://staff.uob.edu.bh/files/600435156_files/The_Comp_lab_3.pdf)

[winZip command line Reference 2](http://www.memecode.com/docs/winzip.html)

To provide multiple file names you can also use **@filename** where the **filename** is a file which contains the list of files which you want to include in the zip file.

If you are making the command configurable then you can ask the user/ other program which is calling your command to select the file extensions and then write these selected extensions into the **"filename"** file using java code or any other language you prefer.

For example if the user selects **bat** and **dat** , then write **"C:\SourcePath\*.bat**" and **"C:\SourcePath\*.dat"** into the file(assume filename is **fileExtensions.txt**) and call the command

```
wzzip.exe -a -p -r "C:\DestinationPath\DataFiles_20130903.zip" @"C:\SourcePath\fileExtensions.txt"
```

Comment: The two hyperlinks for WinZip command reference are broken now.  The first one in says that the website was disabled by the server administrator.  The second one has a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the D7zip

An excellent zipador file and folders D7zip.exe

link to download

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4bu9X3c-WZqdlVlZFV4Wl9QWDA/edit?usp=sharing

How to use

**compressing files**

```
D7Zip.exe -z "c:\fileout.zip" -f "C:\filein.txt"
```

**compressing files and putting password**

```
D7Zip.exe -z "c:\fileout.zip" -f "C:\filein.txt" -s "123"
```

**compressing folders**

```
D7Zip.exe -z "c:\folderout.zip" -f "C:\folderin\"
```

**unzipping files**

```
D7Zip.exe -u "c:\fileout.zip" -f "c:\folderout\"
```

**unzipping files that have password**

```
D7Zip.exe -u "c:\fileout.zip" -f "c:\folderout\" -s "123"
```

**decompressing files by extension**

```
D7Zip.exe -u "c:\fileout.zip" -f "c:\folderout\*.txt"
```

**decompressing files without asking for confirmation to replace**

```
D7Zip.exe -u "c:\fileout.zip" -f "c:\folderout\" -r
```

**help**

```
D7Zip.exe -?
```

D7Zip.exe by Delmar Grande.

Answer (score 0):

If the command line given above is right then give this a go: but check the paths.

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\SourcePath"
"c:\program files\winzip\wzzip.exe" -a -p -r "C:\DestinationPath\DataFiles_20130903.zip" *.dat *.bat
popd
```